# Cannot read properties of undefined using "This" in JavaScript class

Tags: node.js, express, class, oop

I'm using Node JS and ExpressJS to write my web server. I use JavaScript OOP fromfew time. I get an error running this class:

```
class myClass  {

  constructor(path) {
    this.path = path;
  }


      
    myFunction(){

      var fileControllerInstance = new FileController(this.path);

      fileControllerInstance.fileExist(function(fileExist) {
        if(fileExist){
          console.log("file exist");
          this.printLine("test");
        }
        else
          return false;
      });
        
    }


    printSTR(str){
      console.log(str);
    }


    
}

new myClass("filePath").myFunction();
module.exports = myClass;
```

Running this class I get an error on printSTR function. Error is the follow:

```
file exist
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'printSTR')
```

Without `this` I get `ReferenceError: printSTR is not defined`. To solve my problem I need to create another class instance and to use that to call the function. Something like this:

````
new myClass("filePath").printSTR("test") instead to ``` this.printLine("test"); ```
````

Why using `this` my code not working? Thanks

Comment: you have named your method `printSTR` and try to call `printLine`. I'm not sure this is the problem for the error you're getting, but it's a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `function(fileExist)`, `this` has a different value than outside. To inherit the value inside, you must bind the function:

```js
fileControllerInstance.fileExist(function(fileExist) {
  ...
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Now its clear. Thanks.  Its working.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `this` inside a callback. You can find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/12003966) useful to solve your issue.

Also you try to call `printLine("test")` but your method is `printSTR(str)`